# Android: Sharing database data between main activity and Fragment page in another Activity

Tags: android, database, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I've got a main activity that reads a list of categories from a database and displays them in a ListView.

Clicking on one opens a second FragmentActivity which display all items in the category in another list. That's implemented with a Fragment and FragmentPagerAdapter to allow swiping through the categories.

My problem is that I need to access the array of categories in the OnCreateView of the Fragment, in order to work out which category I should be displaying for a given page. Every pager example I've come across either just display e.g. 'page #1', or stores the data in a static array in the fragment.

At the moment, I'm:

- iterating through the cursor in the main activity and storing the categories in an array;
- passing that array to the second activity as extra data in the intent
- extracting the extra data in the second activity and storing it in a class array;
- adding a function getCategories in the activity which returns the array;
- in OnCreateView for the Fragment, calling getActivity().getCategories() to get the array

This seems a bit long winded, and I'm sure there must be a better way of doing it. Is there either a better way of passing the data through, or some other way of accessing the DB so I only need to read it once, but can access the data from both the main activity and the fragment?